# Ошибка переадресации страницы

Tags: header, php

Добрый день! Делаю сайт. На одной странице сделал переадресацию на другую страницу при помощи header. Получаю предупреждение:

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by 
(output started at S:\home\localhost\www\web_shop\admin_header.php:97)
in S:\home\localhost\www\web_shop\add_good.php on line 71
```

В файле admin_header.php у меня следующий фрагмент кода (привожу с 96 строки код):

```
<ul>
<?php 
    $result = List_categories("");
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
      echo '<li><a href="admin.php?cat='.$row['id_cat'].'">'.$row['Name_cat'].'</a></li>';
    }           
?>
</ul>
```

А в файле add_good.php на 71 строке следущий код начинается:

```
header("http://localhost/web_shop/admin.php");
exit();
```

Структура сайта такова: Файл конфиг (в котором на первой строке открывается сессия) подключается к admin_header.php. Последний файл в свою очередь подключается к файлам
admin.php и `add_good`.php. Что я не так делаю? В чем ошибка?

Comment: во первых хедер неправильный, во вторых хедеры надо посылать до любого вывода. вам так и написали, вот этот '<ul>' выводится раньше чем header()

Comment: а как же тогда сделать переадресацию на другую страницу в моем случае? Неужели с середины страницы никак нельзя перейти на другую страницу?

Answer (score 1):

Правильно отправлять заголовок надо так:

```
header("Location: <адрес переадресации>");
```

Из источника одного прочитал, что можно воспользоваться им только в том случае, если перед её использованием на страницу ничего не выводилось. Наличие на странице даже одного пробела приведёт к ошибке.

Это же правило распространяется на функции setcookie() и session_start().
Средствами JS можно использовать переадресацию из любой позиции кода, независимо от того вывелось что-то на экран или нет. Вот короткий код на JS:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
      window.location = "admin.php"
      </script>';
```

А переадресацию методами php можно сделать только до вывода чего-либо. В другом случае есть два варианта: воспользоваться функциями [`ob_start()`](http://www.php.su/functions/?ob-start) и [`ob_end_flush()`](http://www.php.su/functions/?ob-end-flush) или методами HTML.

Comment: Всегда дешевле просто отправить заголовок с переадресацией, чем отдавать пользователю целую страницу, пусть и в очень урезанном варианте.

Comment: через средства js заработало!!! Ура! Код echo '<script type="text/javascript">
      window.location = "admin.php"
      </script>'; подходит для решения задач, когда переадресация идет с середины страницы, когда уже вывод страницы и заголовков произошел.

Answer (score 0):

В начало файла admin_header.php добавь

```
<?php 
    $result = List_categories("");
    $list = '';
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
      $list .= '<li><a href="admin.php?cat='.$row['id_cat'].'">'.$row['Name_cat'].'</a></li>';
    }           
?>
```

Эту часть с 96 строки

```
<ul>
<?php 
    $result = List_categories("");
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
      echo '<li><a href="admin.php?cat='.$row['id_cat'].'">'.$row['Name_cat'].'</a></li>';
    }           
?>
</ul>
```

замени на

```
<ul>
<?=$list;>
</ul>
```

и, конечно же, правильно отправить http-заголовок(ман http://php.net/manual/ru/function.header.php). В файле add_good.php

```
header("http://localhost/web_shop/admin.php");
```

заменить на

```
header('Location: http://localhost/web_shop/admin.php');
```

Comment: такой вариант не подойдет. Дело в том, что у меня еще много подобного кода в admin_header.php и в самом add_good.php прежде чем идет переадресация страницы. Придется весь код переделывать из-за этого... Нужен какой-то другой вариант.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  ob_start();
```

в начале основного скрипта

```
ob_end_flush();
```

в конце.

А `header` с переадресацией заключите в die();

```
die(header('Location: ' . URL));
```

Костыль, но лучше, чем переадресация средствами js.

Comment: а чем переадресация средствами js плоха? У вас тоже выглядит код выглядит не айс.

Comment: все заработало. Спасибо за еще один вариант рабочей переадресации. Хотя это все же костыль тоже.